# Disabling Japanese IME through ADB shell

Tags: android, android-layout

How to disable Japanese IME through ADB shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adb shell mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system
adb shell rm /system/app/PinyinIME.apk
```

This worked for me.