# An improvisation over wait-for-device in adb?

Tags: shell, adb, android-input-method

I have a command that accesses the Input Method Manager and want it to run immediately as my emulator boots. Here's one of those commands:

```
adb wait-for-device shell ime disable com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME
```

I ran my Android 2.3.3 emulator as a process **not** run from the terminal. Then opened the terminal and ran the command written above. It apparently waited only for the device status to turn to `device` and returned errors saying that the Input Method Manager could not be accessed! So I would like to know whether there is an option in place of `wait-for-device` which ensures that the command waits, not only until the status of the device is `device` but until the home screen shows up? Or is there an entirely different way to ensure that a specific command executes, immediately after the home screen shows up?

I googled, and in particular searched developer.android.com for options, couldn't find one convenient as one that could be fed into an `adb` command.

**UPDATE:** I tried

```
adb wait-for-device sleep 200
adb shell ime disable com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME
```

It sleeps 200 seconds after the emulator status turns `device`. This way there is higher probability the IME command executes error-free.

There are ways to ensure that the even SD card is mounted, but they involve java, and not adb commands. Right now I am not familiar with linking the output of a java program to an adb command.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also posted on [android](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47371/1302)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question about waiting for the IME to be up, however I noticed your trying to disable an IME.

If this is actually your goal maybe try the following post, but for latin.

[Disabling Japanese IME through ADB shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115955/disabling-japanese-ime-through-adb-shell)

Comment: Right! Had never occurred to me I could actually remove those IMEs! Removed 3 of the 4 IMEs. Can you help me remove Sample Soft Keyboard too? I am searching for the apk... I want to use exclusively the hardware keyboard for my purposes.

Comment: Im stuck on the same issue. How do I detect that the screen has booted up? wait-for-device exits way too early. Adding sleep is not a sure shot solution :(